# Sans serif caption (lmss not available)

Tags: fonts, captions, sans-serif

I'd like to switch to sans serif in order to make my text dyslexic-friendly.

Unfortunately, captions still have serif, and it raises a warning:

```
Font shape 'T1/lmss/m/sc' in size <12> not available
Font shape 'T1/lmr/m/sc' tried instead
```

I (obviously) used lmodern, I tried `\usepackage{anyfontsize}` and several other tricks, but it won't work. Any idea?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}        %article, report, book

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}           
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                  
\usepackage{textcomp}                                           
\usepackage[gen]{eurosym}                                   
\usepackage{gensymb}                            
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}    
\usepackage{graphicx}                                           
\usepackage{amsmath}                                            
\usepackage{mathtools, bm}
\usepackage{amssymb, bm}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}      
\usepackage{nccrules}                                       
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}                      
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}                                   
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}                             
\usepackage{geometry}                       
\usepackage{parskip}                                            
\usepackage{lmodern}                                            

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}   % Supprime le serif (dyslexie)
%\usepackage[font=sf, labelfont={sf}]{caption}
%\usepackage[font=sf]{floatrow}
\linespread{1.2}                                                    
\geometry{hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=2.5cm}      
%\pagestyle{empty}                                      
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7 \textwidth]{Deb.jpg}
    \caption{Leviers}
    \label{Leviers}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There is no small caps in the Latin Modern Sans fonts.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

french changes the font in caption to small caps, and as there is no small caps for sans serif latin modern you get a replacement. You can avoid this like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}   

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel} %use french instead of the outdated francais
\frenchsetup{SmallCapsFigTabCaptions=false}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}   % Supprime le serif (dyslexie)
\usepackage[font=sf, labelfont={sf}]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering

    a figure

    \caption{Leviers}
    \label{Leviers}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```